# How listeners work

Tags: java, android

Can someone please tell me how the  listener interface works, when you set a onclicklistener, what really happens in the background?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html

Comment: SO really needs mods that can read.  "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form"  Not a single one of these reasons actually apply to this question, so why was it closed?  Yes the guy could have done a bit of research on google, however, again as with many other decisions on here, it's just "power" going to many mods heads.

Comment: Instead of Closing this Question..and applying that much of efforts in Closing this Question,the Moderators would have applied their efforts in referring a link that would help that Guy to solve his actual problem...Is it not the motto of Stack Overflow to help the needy?? Then why not the Moderators instead of helping the Guy,close this question???Is this Question attempting to mis-use Stack Overflow ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listener you registered gets added to a list of listeners, and when the operating system receives an event (click in this case), it calls the appropriate methods on all the listeners in the list.

Comment: Is the OS running a while loop forever?